# error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. [currentPrice]="listing.price"

Tags: angular, typescript

In my personal project, i stuck with a error. 
Basically I want to autofill the current data that i have, in the Input field in edit-listing-component.html.
To achieve this i created a parent component named Listing-data-form-component, with @input tag made

```
@Input() currentName = '';
@Input() currentDescription = '';
@Input() currentPrice = '';
```

here is the link 
https://github.com/abhijitutkarsh/buyandsell/blob/last-update/src/app/listing-data-form/listing-data-form.component.ts 

and in the edit-listing-component.html i called it, link here is the code 
https://github.com/abhijitutkarsh/buyandsell/blob/last-update/src/app/edit-listing-page/edit-listing-page.component.html

the matter is, my currentName and currentDesciption is working just perfectly that is data is getting autofilled since they are string
the issue is coming with the currentPrice since it is number....i am not able to identify how to resolve this

```
Error 
error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

7     [currentPrice]="listing.price"
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/edit-listing-page/edit-listing-page.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './edit-listing-page.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component EditListingPageComponent.
```

Kindly help

Comment: You are passing the value with `number` type. While the component is expected to receive `currentPrice` with `string` type. Specify the currentPrice as `number` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this way.

```
   @Input() currentPrice: number;
   or 
   @Input() currentPrice = 0;
```